# App Crashes After Send json object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsurlconnection

[image]

Hi,
i am tryng to send json object with `NSUrlconnection` with this sample code below...
the app crashes after she hit the last line : `[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];`

any idea?

Comment: What kind of crash it is? EXEC_BAD_ACCESS? Try log request, is it nil?

Comment: 2011-11-07 12:15:24.492[32203:707] -[__NSCFString bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2b0ac0
2011-11-07 12:15:26.043[32203:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2b0ac0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x30e398bf 0x37fde1e5 0x30e3cacb 0x30e3b945 0x30d96680 0x30d88bdd 0x36078511 0x360782f1 0x360782c9 0x36078293 0x361112c1 0x3607822d 0x360781a7 0x36078173 0x36077785 0x360775c1 0x3607729f 0x360771d5 0x.......

Comment: The error says that you're sending the message bytes to an instance of NSCFString,

Comment: i need to send json object wich contain the receipt data bytes and password to apple.

Comment: i have it formated in the wright way in nsstring... maybe i need to convert it to json?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
- (void)setHTTPBody:(NSData *)data
```

need NSData* to work

Try with:

```
NSData *requestdata = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[request setHTTPBody:requestData];
```

Comment: i need to cancel this line? 
NSData *requestdata = [NSData dataWithBytes:[jsonString UTF8String] length:[jsonString length]];

Comment: No replace it with NSData *requestdata = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

Comment: the App still crashes the same way

Answer (score 0):

```
+ (id)dataWithBytes:(const void *)bytes length:(NSUInteger)length   

bytes:
A buffer containing data for the new object.
length:
The number of bytes to copy from bytes. This value must not exceed the length of bytes.
```

First argument is not `NSString` and you are providing `NSString`.